# Почему не срабатывает фильтр после удаления сессии в Java?

Tags: java, jsp, сессия, filter, jstl

На JSP странице с я устанавливаю ResourceBundle (перевод берется из properties файлов) и устанавливаю соответствующую локаль переменной `${locale}` с областью видимости в пределах сессии:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="locale"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${locale}" scope="session"/>
```

Как задается значение переменной `value="${locale}"`? Она устанавливается в фильтре, который, по идее, должен срабатывать перед сервлетом. А вот и сам фильтр:

```java
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        if(session.isNew()) {
            session.setAttribute("locale", "en_US");
            LOGGER.info("Default locale page set to '{}'.", "en_US");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Имеется фильтр, который из запроса (`HttpServletRequest`) получает сессиию (`HttpSession`) и при условии того, что сессия новая (проверяется в условии `if(session.isNew())`), устанавливает в сессии атрибут с ключом `locale` значение `en_US` (устанавливает дефолтную локаль для JSP страницы в английскую).

Сам фильтр и маппинг фильтра содержатся в `web.xml` и выглядит следующим образом:

```xml
<!-- Set default locale filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>DefaultLocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>by.ct.controller.filter.DefaultLocaleFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DefaultLocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Вроде всё в порядке. Идём дальше. В каталоге `webapp` содержится `index.jsp`, которая автоматически подгружается при обращении к `localhost`. В самой `index.jsp` стоит перенаправление на другую страницу `main.jsp`, не доступную "извне", так как она располагается по пути `/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp'.`   index.jsp` выглядит следующим образом:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="с" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
    <jsp:forward page="WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Так вот, вопрос собственно в чем. Когда я на странице `main.jsp` делаю выход из аккаунта, идет обращение на сервлет, там определяется, что пришла команда "logout", выполняется данная команда (она делает `session.invalidate()`) и делает `forward` на `index.jsp` (которая делает `forward` на `main.jsp`). И в промежутке между выполнением `logout` и форварде на `index.jsp` (которая делает `forward` на `main.jsp` ) не запускается фильтр. Почему?

Нужно, чтобы фильтр сработал после логаута. Что я пробовал сделать (это, естественно, весь написанный код и плюс):

1. В `index.jsp` я менял способ переадресации на `main.jsp` таким образом:

```
1) <jsp:forward page="WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp"/>
2) <c:redirect url="сontroller?command=go_to_main_page"/> (через сервлет)
```

Насколько я понимаю, при использовании второго способа будет обращение к контроллеру, а так как идет обращение к контроллеру, то перед этим запустится фильтр, но он не запускается.
Сижу 2 полных дня, сегодня 3, не могу понять, почему не срабатывает фильтр для установки локали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В то время, пока тут "мегаумы" пытаются заминусовать вопрос по надуманным причинам, находится ответ - `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`:
`web.xml`:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DefaultLocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

*P.S. Минусаторы, пишите в комментарии свои обоснования. Хотя я вас понимаю, стыдно писать, когда нечего ответить...*